# Passing postid of Testimonial Custom Post in Shortcode Parameter

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, theme-development, shortcode

I am trying to create Testimonial custom post and display using shortcode

```
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type(
        'testimonials',//new post type
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Testimonials' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Testimonial' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','custom_fields'),
            'hierarchical' => false
        )
    );  
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );

//adding the URL meta box field
function add_custom_metabox() {
    add_meta_box( 'custom-metabox', __( 'Link' ), 'url_custom_metabox', 'testimonials', 'side', 'low' );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_custom_metabox' );

// HTML for the admin area
function url_custom_metabox() {
    global $post;
    $urllink = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'urllink', true );

    //validating!
    if ( ! preg_match( "/http(s?):\/\//", $urllink ) && $urllink != "") {
        $errors = "This URL isn't valid";
        $urllink = "http://";
    } 

    // output invlid url message and add the http:// to the input field
    if( isset($errors) ) { echo $errors; }
?>  
<p>
    <label for="siteurl">URL:<br />
        <input id="siteurl" size="37" name="siteurl" value="<?php if( isset($urllink) ) { echo $urllink; } ?>" />
    </label>
</p>
<?php
}

//saves custom field data
function save_custom_url( $post_id ) {
    global $post;   

    if( isset($_POST['siteurl']) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'urllink', $_POST['siteurl'] );
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_custom_url' );

//return URL for a post
function get_url($post) {
    $urllink = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'urllink', true );

    return $urllink;
}

//registering the shortcode to show testimonials
function load_testimonials($a){

    $args = array(
        "post_type" => "testimonials",
        "id"       =>  $post->ID
    );

    if( isset( $a['rand'] ) && $a['rand'] == true ) {
        $args['orderby'] = 'rand';
    }
    if( isset( $a['max'] ) ) {
        $args['posts_per_page'] =(int) $a['max'];
    }
    if( $a['id'] ) {
    $posts_in = array_map( 'intval', explode( ',',$a['id'] ) );
    $args['post__in'] = $posts_in;
    }
    //getting all testimonials
    $posts = get_posts($args);

    echo '<div id="testimonials" class="flexslider">';
        echo '<ul class="slides">';

        foreach($posts as $post)
        {

            $url_thumb = wp_get_attachment_thumb_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID));
            $link = get_url($post);
            echo '<li>';
            echo '<div class="slide-testimonials">';
                if ( ! empty( $url_thumb ) ) { echo '<img src="'.$url_thumb.'" />'; }
                if ( ! empty( $post->post_content ) ) { echo '<p>'.$post->post_content.'<br />'; }
                echo '<h2>'.$post->post_title.'</h2>';
                if ( ! empty( $link ) ) { echo '<a href="'.$link.'">Visit Site</a></p>'; }
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</li>';
        }

        echo '</ul>';
    echo '</div>';
}
add_shortcode("testimonials","load_testimonials");

add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

and the shortcode for display i used is

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[testimonials id=3751]'); ?>
```

I want to pass post id in shortcode and display that particular post id in my page. I am trying to do this but it not showing any output please suggest me where i am wrong your suggestions help me a lot.

Comment: I know i am doing wrong somewhere in my code please suggest me some solutions.

Comment: Please friends suggest some suggestions really each suggestion help me a lot

Comment: finally i have done it Check my updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe you shouldn't set $args['posts id'] as this is not a supported argument for the get_posts function and instead use the "posts__in" argument or instead switch to the "get_post" function if you get the id parameter. Also, i'm not quite sure but i think you have to use quotes in the shortcode.

So your Shortcode function should look like this:

```
function load_testimonials($a){
     $thePostID = $post->ID;
    $args = array(
        "post_type" => "testimonials",
        "id"       =>  $post->ID
    );

    if( isset( $a['rand'] ) && $a['rand'] == true ) {
        $args['orderby'] = 'rand';
    }
    if( isset( $a['max'] ) ) {
        $args['posts_per_page'] =(int) $a['max'];
    }
    if(isset( $a['id'])){
     echo   $args['posts__in'] = array((int)$a['id']);
    }
    //getting all testimonials
    $posts = get_posts($args);

    echo '<div id="testimonials" class="flexslider">';
        echo '<ul class="slides">';

        foreach($posts as $post)
        {

            $url_thumb = wp_get_attachment_thumb_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID));
            $link = get_url($post);
            echo '<li>';
            echo '<div class="slide-testimonials">';
                if ( ! empty( $url_thumb ) ) { echo '<img src="'.$url_thumb.'" />'; }
                if ( ! empty( $post->post_content ) ) { echo '<p>'.$post->post_content.'<br />'; }
                echo '<h2>'.$post->post_title.'</h2>';
                if ( ! empty( $link ) ) { echo '<a href="'.$link.'">Visit Site</a></p>'; }
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</li>';
        }

        echo '</ul>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[testimonials id="3751"]'); ?>
```

Happy Coding,

Kuchenundkakao

Comment: Thanks @kuchenundkakao for your suggestions still my problem remain the same

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. This is a pretty basic code and you might need to modify it to get it fully work, but it will get you started.

```
function load_testimonials( $atts ) {


    extract( shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'id' => '',
        ), $atts )
    );

    $out = '<div id="testimonials" class="flexslider">';
        $out .= '<ul class="slides">';

        $post = get_post( $id );
        if ( $post) {
        $url_thumb = wp_get_attachment_thumb_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID));
        $link = get_url($post);
            $out .= '<li>';
                $out .= '<div class="slide-testimonials">';
                    ....
                    ....
                $out .= '</div>';
            $out .= '</li>';
        }
        $out .= '</ul>';
    $out .= '</div>';


    return $out;
}
add_shortcode( 'testimonials', 'load_testimonials' );
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use `get_the_ID()` then it will get the `ID` of the Post when shortcode is placed inside the loop of post, page or custom post type, outside the loop we have a **global variable** `$post` which contain the **post object**, to get the `ID` outside the loop you can use `$post->ID`

in shorcode i suggest you to use `$post->ID` if the shortcode is inside the loop it will get the id of that post otherwise it will get the `ID` of the first post.

Answer (score -1):

Just replace your short code function with given code. Then call it as usual. It should work perfectly now.

```
//registering the shortcode to show testimonials
    function load_testimonials($a){
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'rand' => '',
        'max' => '',
        'id' => '',
    ), $a);

$args = array(
    "post_type" => "testimonials",
);

if( isset( $a['rand'] ) && $a['rand'] == true ) {
    $args['orderby'] = 'rand';
}
if( isset( $a['max'] ) ) {
    $args['posts_per_page'] =(int) $a['max'];
}
if( $a['id'] ) {
$posts_in = array_map( 'intval', explode( ',',$a['id'] ) );
$args['post__in'] = $posts_in;
}
//getting all testimonials
$posts = get_posts($args);

echo '<div id="testimonials" class="flexslider">';
    echo '<ul class="slides">';

    foreach($posts as $post)
    {

        $url_thumb = wp_get_attachment_thumb_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID));
        $link = get_url($post);
        echo '<li>';
        echo '<div class="slide-testimonials">';
            if ( ! empty( $url_thumb ) ) { echo '<img src="'.$url_thumb.'" />'; }
            if ( ! empty( $post->post_content ) ) { echo '<p>'.$post->post_content.'<br />'; }
            echo '<h2>'.$post->post_title.'</h2>';
            if ( ! empty( $link ) ) { echo '<a href="'.$link.'">Visit Site</a></p>'; }
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</li>';
    }

    echo '</ul>';
echo '</div>';
}
add_shortcode("testimonials","load_testimonials");
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?